# PHP: creating table with conditions

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I have array like this in php:

```
    $arr = [
    [
        "group": 1,
        "name": John
    ],
    [
        "group": 1,
        "name": Luke
    ],
    [
        "group": 1,
        "name": Peter
    ],
    [
        "group": 2,
        "name": Pia
    ]
]
```

expected output in html table:

```
GROUP | NAME
------|-----
      | John
  1   | Luke
      | Peter 
------|-----
  2   | Pia
```

I attempted to work around the `foreach` but i cant figure it out. Below is the last code i tried:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>GROUP</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <?php $group = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach($results AS $result) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php if($group !== $result['group']): ?>
                        <?= $result['group'] ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li><?= $result['name'] ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php $group = $result['group']; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

but the result is:

```
GROUP | NAME
------|-----
   1  | John
------|-----
      | Luke
------|-----
      | Peter 
------|-----
  2   | Pi
```

I need to show it as the about expected output.

Please help, thanks

Comment: Your question would be nice if you put your tried code also.

Comment: @Epodax,  hi, i updated the question, kindly check. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make group first like below

```
<?php
    $results = [
        ["group"=> 1,"name"=> "John"],
        ["group"=> 1,"name"=> "Luke"],
        ["group"=> 1,"name"=> "Peter"],
        ["group"=> 2,"name"=> "Pia"]
    ];
    $newArr = array();
    foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
        $newArr[$value["group"]][] = $value["name"];
    }
?>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>GROUP</th><th>NAME</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach($newArr as $group=>$values){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $group;?></td>
            <td>
                <ul style="margin: 5px;">
                <?php 
                    foreach($values as $key=>$name){
                        echo "<li>$name</li>";
                    }
                ?>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Which will give output,

[image]

Comment: Ah, seems like we reached the same soloution, although yours is a lot prettier than mine.

Comment: Yes you are right. same solution is expected but the timing exactly after 1 hour is really amazing :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, since its more readable to me, i will accept this as an answer. 

@Epodax Thank you too. i got some ideas from you answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a little counting and some CSS magic. Add the first block of code anywhere below your array and above your table.

```
$d = array();
foreach($results as $c){
    if(array_key_exists($c['group'],$d)){
        $d[$c['group']]++;
    }else{
        $d[$c['group']] = 1;
    }
}
```

And then change your tbody code to this:

```
<tbody>
        <?php $group = ''; ?>
        <?php foreach($results AS $result) : ?>
        <?php $t = $result['group']; ?>
            <tr>

                    <?php if($group !== $result['group']): ?>
                    <?php echo '<td rowspan="' . $d[$t] . '" style="vertical-align:middle;">'; ?>
                        <?= $result['group'] ?>
                             </td>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <li><?= $result['name'] ?></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php $group = $result['group']; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
```

Mind you this is just a mockup that should work but it's very basic and you'll properly need to beautify it a little.

Further more, you could remove the counting if you grouped your array's by "group" instead of having each person hold the group as well.